# neo4j get relationship value by python

Tags: python, neo4j

I created a relationship, now I want to get the value of the relationship.

My Python script below:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
from neo4j.v1 import Record as Record
result=session.run('''MATCH (:Person {mobile:111111111})-[r]-() RETURN r''')
listresult= list(result)
for x in list(result):
    print x
```

Returned value :

```
<Record r=<Relationship id=2 start=26 end=27 type=u'CONTRACT20161118' properties={u'grade': [400], u'month': [20161118]}>>
<Record r=<Relationship id=1 start=26 end=27 type=u'CONTRACT' properties={u'grade': [800], u'month': [20161117]}>>
```

How can I get the record type returned value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `x` that you print is actually a `Record` instance. Think of that `Record` instance as a result row: for each alias you return in Cypher, there is a "cell" in each "row" that corresponds to that alias in that record. You can access these by numeric index (`x[0]`, `x[1]`) corresponding to the order in the `RETURN` statement, or by the actual alias assigned in the `RETURN` statement (in this case, since you `RETURN r`, you would want to access `x['r']`). This will let you access the actual `Relationship` instance that has your data, which has the attributes `id`, `type`, `start`, `end`, and `properties`, the last being a `dict`-alike of the relationship's assigned properties.

It is generally considered best practice to only return the info you need from a Cypher statement, so if you only wanted relationship type, your Cypher statement should finish with `RETURN TYPE(r)`, and then you could grab `x['TYPE(r)']` to just get the type. If you just want the properties, `RETURN PROPERTIES(r)` and `x['PROPERTIES(r)']`. The string key used in a `Record` must match exactly the alias as returned; if you want to make it easier to parse, assign an alias in the `RETURN` statement, like `RETURN TYPE(r) AS a`, and the corresponding `x['a']`.

As an aside, you also don't need to import anything from `neo4j.v1` except `GraphDatabase` and `basic_auth`, everything else should be instantiated under the covers by methods derived from `GraphDatabase`.

Comment: you are right ! thanks ! i change like this result=session.run('''MATCH (:Person {mobile:15309912652})-[r]-() RETURN PROPERTIES(r)''')
#
for x in result:
    print x['PROPERTIES(r)']